# Problem while scraping hotel price from booking.com

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, empty-list

I just started learning python and I am trying to extract hotel info from booking.com, the ideal result is to print out a list of hotel names, hotel links, and hotel prices respectively.

The problem I encountered is that my code works at the beginning and I was able to export the output to another file, but after a few days, when I run the code again, I have no problems getting hotel names and links, but I couldn't get hotel prices since I only got a empty list for it.

Please see my code below. Can anyone help me figure out what the problem is?

```
import lxml
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4 import NavigableString
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver

url = "https://www.booking.com/searchresults.en-gb.html?aid=356980&label=gog235jc-1FCAsoqQFCCHB1bGl0emVySDNYA2ipAYgBAZgBCbgBF8gBDNgBAegBAfgBDIgCAagCA7gCy_H09QXAAgE&sid=11df088cc51daa70cb9f00a605f6318d&sb=1&src=hotel&src_elem=sb&error_url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.booking.com%2Fhotel%2Fnl%2Fpulitzer.en-gb.html%3Faid%3D356980%3Blabel%3Dgog235jc-1FCAsoqQFCCHB1bGl0emVySDNYA2ipAYgBAZgBCbgBF8gBDNgBAegBAfgBDIgCAagCA7gCy_H09QXAAgE%3Bsid%3D11df088cc51daa70cb9f00a605f6318d%3Ball_sr_blocks%3D1052724_127806409_0_2_0%3Bcheckin%3D2020-06-01%3Bcheckout%3D2020-06-02%3Bdest_id%3D-2140479%3Bdest_type%3Dcity%3Bdist%3D0%3Bgroup_adults%3D2%3Bgroup_children%3D0%3Bhapos%3D1%3Bhighlighted_blocks%3D1052724_127806409_0_2_0%3Bhpos%3D1%3Bno_rooms%3D1%3Broom1%3DA%252CA%3Bsb_price_type%3Dtotal%3Bshow_room%3D1052724%3Bsr_order%3Dpopularity%3Bsr_pri_blocks%3D1052724_127806409_0_2_0__52108%3Bsrepoch%3D1589459170%3Bsrpvid%3Dff6f5770f10b008a%3Btype%3Dtotal%3Bucfs%3D1%26%3B&highlighted_hotels=10527&hp_sbox=1&ss=Amsterdam&is_ski_area=0&ssne=Amsterdam&ssne_untouched=Amsterdam&dest_id=-2140479&dest_type=city&checkin_year=2020&checkin_month=7&checkin_monthday=1&checkout_year=2020&checkout_month=7&checkout_monthday=2&group_adults=1&group_children=0&no_rooms=1&from_sf=1"

options = selenium.webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("headless")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Users\abc\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\chromedriver.exe')

driver.get(url)
src = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(src, "lxml")

hotel_names = []
for hotel_name in soup.find_all("span", class_="sr-hotel__name"):
    hotel_name = hotel_name.string.replace('\n', '')
    hotel_names.append(hotel_name)


hotel_urls = []
booking_url = 'http//:www.booking.com'

for hotel_src in soup.find_all('a', class_='hotel_name_link url'):
    hotel_src = 'https//:www.booking.com{}'.format(hotel_src['href']).replace('\n','')
    hotel_urls.append(hotel_src)

hotel_prices = []
for hotel_price in soup.find_all(class_='bui-price-display__value prco-text-nowrap-helper prco-inline-block-maker-helper'):
    hotel_price = hotel_price.string
    hotel_price = ' '.join(hotel_price.split())
    hotel_prices.append(hotel_price)

print(hotel_names)
print(hotel_urls)
print(hotel_prices)
```

Comment: Scraping booking.com is against their TOS

Comment: Print out the html when you get the empty list. Most likely bookings.com detected that you are scraping their site and blocked your script.

Comment: @MikeScotty, I know it is not a nice thing to do. but I am in hotel business and it is just more interesting for me to learn python by doing projects related to my field....

Comment: @VinayPai so the problem is not in my code? am I blocked by booking.com somehow?

Comment: if you open too many pages in short time then it may know that it can't be human but script. Strange can be also that you don't open main page as first. And some servers have method to recognize `Selenium`. BTW: you can also try to use proxy servers to use different IPs in requests.

Comment: @furas, Thanks for the tip, I will try it.

Comment: BTW: there are many sites with [free proxies]https://free-proxy-list.net/) but free proxies sometimes don't work or they are already blocked by portals - but it is still some method to get free proxies. You may even find tutorials which use `requests` + `BeautifulSoup` to scrape these IPs.